# App Store links don't work when App Store is running

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

I have a 32 GB iPad 3 with WiFi. If I try to follow an app store link, like from Safari or AppShopper, it will activate the running instance of the App Store but will not navigate to the link destination. If I force close the App Store and try again, it will launch the App Store and navigate to the right destination.

The problem is 100% reproducible. I have tried restarting the iPad and disabling\enabling Safari.

I've also found this link which describes my problem ([here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3819947?start=0&tstart=0)), but I can't figure out how to apply the solution there without losing my data.

Comment: have you ever synced your iPad with a computer or did you set up your iPad from the device itself?

Answer (score 1):

It's annoying, but if you force close the App Store each time, it will pull up the correct link when you reopen it.